# Number of integers covered

Tags: combinatorics

Let $x_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ for ${i=1}$ to ${m}$ and for ${j=1}$ to $n$. How many different values does $$\prod_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nx_{ij}$$ cover?

Is there an $a_{ij}$ such that $$\prod_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_{ij}$$ for which we cover least number of distinct values as compared to that values covered by first formula?

Comment: Turbo: I've added to my answer below something about the second question concerning choosing $a_{ij}$ to decrease the number of distinct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $m=2$ this is one more (for the $0$) than the number of distinct products $s \cdot t$ with $s,t \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}.$ The latter number is for $n=1,2,...$ the sequence $1,3,6,9,14,18$ which certainly no simple formula is known to produce. It is discussed as an o.e.i.s. sequence [A027424](https://oeis.org/A027424).

For larger $m$ it would seem unlikely for there to be a closed formula, since even for $m=2$ there doesn't seem to be a known one. However note one of the links from the o.e.i.s. is to a paper discussing the more general case of an arbitrary number of factors. (Unfortunately that link only lets one see an outline, and refers to yet another site where the final paper might be found.)

*Added note* about the second part of the question about $a_{ij}$ choice: It may not be optimal, but choosing $a_{ij}=(-1)^{j+1}$ certainly brings the count down. Suppose $n=2k$ is even. Then the sums for a fixed row $j$ of the terms $a_{ij}x_{ij}=(-1)^{j+1}x_{ij}$ have as possible values the integers in the interval $[-k,k].$ If we omit the zero choice here (later one can add $1$ to the sum) then the possible values of the product are each up to a sign of $\pm 1$ the nonzero values of the original unaltered sum for parameters $(m,n)=(m,k).$ To state this more clearly, let $1+S(m,n)$ be the number covered as in the post, while $1+T(m,n)$ the number covered with our choice of coefficients $a_{ij}.$ Then what we have is $T(m,2k)=2 \cdot S(m,k).$ Even for $m=2$ this gives a significant decrease for the altered sum, comared to the unaltered one.

Comment: Actually I was using $S(m,n)$ (not $S(n,m)$) since in your post the index $m$ is outermost, going over the product. And then because $0$ is one of the possible products, after dropping it there are in my notation $S(m,n)$ nonzero products, each formed by multiplying $m$ terms where each term is between $1$ and $n.$

Comment: Opps so $S(m,n)$ is number of solutions to $∏∑xij$? and $T(m,2n)=2S(m,n)$?

Comment: Yes on the second part of this comment, i.e. $T(m,2n)=2S(m,n).$ But in the first part of this last comment $m,n$ are still reversed. I see now they are right in first part of comment. Keep in mind in my notation I dropped the $0$ value so $S(m,n)$ is the number of *nonzero* values in the product.

Comment: I am thinking roots of unity will help.

Comment: I thought about that, to make a cycling pattern of things in front of the $x_{ij}$. It may be difficult to keep things all integers if this idea is done, and without that the count may be hard to keep track of, and diffifcult to decrease it (as compared to the unaltered number)

Comment: Here is a variant of problem http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191692/distinct-numbers. Roots of unity help there?

Comment: The link to the paper mentioned is to the arxiv, so the full text is seen by clicking on the PDF link in the top-right corner.  In that paper, it gives a result from a second paper which answers your question; that the number is roughly $$\frac{N^m}{(\log N)^Q(\log\log N)^{3/2}}$$ where $Q=u\log u-u+1$ and $u=(m-1)/\log m$

Answer (score -1):

I suspect this is difficult.  But here is an upper bound.
Each expression is the product of $m$ numbers, each between $0$ and $n$.  If any number is zero, the product is zero.  Otherwise, there are $m$ numbers, each between $1$ and $n$.
By the standard 'stars and bars' argument, there are $m+n-1\choose n-1$ sets, so an upper bound is $$1+{m+n-1\choose n-1}$$
Of course, that doesn't take into account coincidences such as $1*4=2*2$.
A lower bound comes with all $a_i$ primes greater than $\sqrt{n}(i=1..m)$.  All these products are different.  Let $q=\pi(n)-\pi(\sqrt{n})\approx n/\log n$.  The lower bound is $$1+{m+q-1\choose m}$$

Comment: I need exact number (or if a tight matching lower bound is found, that is also be tuned).

Comment: Sorry, I think my number is a poor overestimate.